# How to write custom json converter with custom read and default write?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web API.
Using the `System.Text.Json` (the default lib comes with .net core 3.1) I need to write a `CustomJsonConverter` for a custom generic type (ley's call it `MyType<T>`), but need only to customize the deserialization functionality (only the `Read` method), and leave the `Write` to work as if there was no custom converter to this type, it's an object so I need it to be serialized as an object.

I tried this:

```
public class MyTypeConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T>
  where T : MyType<T>
{
    public override T Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) {  
          // do the custom deserialization
    }
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TEnum value, JsonSerializerOptions options) {
         // I tried the following but it resulted a "string" json object, not object in Json format
         // like this: "{\"Key\":1,\"Value\":\"Male\"},{\"Key\":2,\"Value\":\"Female\"}"
         //JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value, options);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to keep the write as in the default converter?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you can override the method `CanWrite()` and just return false. Then your `Write()` method will never be called.

Comment: @CarstenGehling there isn't such method on `System.Text.Json.JsonConverter`